# Grails: Debugging save() or validate()

Tags: grails

I'm somewhat new to Grails. As I create or update domain object and fire `save()` or `validate()` on an object, if the method fails, the system does not seem throw an exception. I dont see any way to examine what exactly is failing.

A typical snippet:

```
if (domainInstance.validate()) {
  flash.message = "Succesfully updated domain object"
} else {
  flash.message = "Failed to update domain object"
  //throw new RuntimeException("Invalid broker")
  log.error "Failed to update domain object"
}
```

In my case the validate fails, and I am in the dark as to why.
Could anybody shed some light on it?

If placed into a try/catch, this does not throw an exception.

Comment: Please format your code in a code block. Its the 101/010 icon above the textfield.

Answer (score 6):

mydomain.validate() is used to only validate the object. You may use mydomain.hasErrors() to load the errors object and to print what went wrong with the following statement.

```
if(mydomain.hasErrors()){
   mydomain.errors.allErrors.each{println it}
}
```

And generally the way I prefer to save and update any object is

```
if(mydomain.hasErrors() || !mydomain.save(failOnError:true){
  //action to be taken if domain validation fails.
}
```

By setting failOnError:true, if the save() fails, validation exception would be thrown which needs to catched in controller.

Answer (score 4):

You can also set `failOnError = true` for the entire application in the grails config file

```
grails.gorm.failOnError=true
```

http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.3 GORM